# Xamarin forms Entry borders not expanding on some iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue (particularly on iOS devices such as iPhone 6s, 7, Ipad Pro etc) where my entry field under border are not expanding horizontally to the end of the page.

Full Code

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="Logo.png" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

    <Label Text="Welcome" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" />

    <Label Text="I don't have an account - Register" freshEssentials:TappedGestureAttached.Command="{Binding GoToRegisterPageCommand}" TextColor="Accent" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Entry x:Name="EmailEntry" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email" Keyboard="Email">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
          <behaviours:EmailValidatorBehaviour IsValid="{Binding IsEmailValid, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
      </Entry>
      <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" />
      <Label Text="{Binding InstructionText}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The same code displays fine on iPhone 5-5s and all Android devices.

Any ideas? i've tried fiddling with 'fillandexpand' etc on the entrys but nothing seems to be working.

My Xamarin version is 2.3.1.114 (i tried upgrading but was left with an unbuildable project with XAMC errors. can try again if that's what people suggest)

Possibly an issue in the iOS entry renderer?
I've noticed my other entry views also have the same error.

[Not extending borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPdGZ.png)

[More broken borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UylnM.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried Start or StartAndExpand in HorizontalOptions of your entry??

Comment: have u tried `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried both of these answers and they haven't worked.

Comment: Is your StackLayout a child of something? Please show the full layout.

Comment: done @GeraldVersluis

Comment: With latest Xamarin I cannot reproduce it. Tried on simulator phone 6s with and ipad ios 10.3 The only different in my environment I had to comment out behaviours:EmailValidatorBehaviour but I don't think it matters

Comment: Ahh, perhaps it has been fixed in the latest Xamarin forms. Problem was when I upgraded I was left with broken dependency's left right and center. Are you able to install the Xamarin Forms nuget package the same version as mine (2.3.1.114) and see if it will reproduce?

Comment: I managed to upgrade to version 2.3.4.247 but it hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately. I also have a separate project in my solution that uses entry's and they appear fine on these devices!?!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the problem!

Someone in the project had created a custom renderer for all entrys that I was not aware of, and calculating the Frame width incorrectly.